# Is there an href attribute for skype, like "mailto:" or "tel:"?

Tags: url, skype, url-scheme

I am looking to make a skype link for a mobile site, is there a way use `<a href="` to make it launch skype and add or call a user?

Comment: http://enarion.net/programming/c-sharp/skype/html-call/
Check it out... Just a tip, not an answer

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If your mobile site is (generally) used by iOS devices, you can use :

```
<a href="skype:YourSkypeName?call">Call me on Skype</a>
```

Apple iOS devices automatically recognizes intents in link with Skype and FaceTime.

Comment: Just a side note: I'm not sure this happens everywhere, but the ?call seems to be the default behavior and thus can be omitted.

Answer (score 69):

You can use `skype:<username|phonenumber>[?[add|call|chat|sendfile|userinfo]]` or `callto:<screenname|phonenumber>`, according to this wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#callto:

Comment: @Andreas I guess that depends on the browser and platform used and whether the Skype app is installed?

Comment: I guess, im interested in what is being shown if my mobile doesnt have skype installed :) Havent played with this.

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching "skype button to send add to contact request"

Answer (score 8):

To turn your skype id into a link so people can add you to their contact list use the following:

```
<a href="skype:SKYPENAME?add">SKYPENAME</a>
```

Replacing SKYPENAME with your own of course.

Answer (score 7):

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Call the Skype Echo / Sound Test Service</a>
```

According to Skype [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745878.aspx#sectionSection1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<a href="skype:-skype-name-?chat">Start chat</a>`

Allowed query parameters:

`chat` - start a chat

`call` - start a call

`add` - add person to the contacts

`userinfo` - view user's profile

`voicemail` - leave a voice message

`sendfile` - send a file