# Skype for Business - Sharepoint href="sip:..."

Tags: html, sharepoint, href, sip, skype-for-business

I'm new at this, so have no idea really what to do. I'm trying to add a link to a sharepoint page which allows a Skype for Business conversation window to open (like the contact button that works for Skype).  Every example I saw says that the easiest way to do this is by using the following code:

```
<a href="sip:user@domain.com"> Text </a>
```

When I do this and save the sharepoint page the hyperlink dissapears and the code ends up being

```
<a unselectable="on"> Text </a>
```

I don't know if I'm missing a .js or something like that, which allows the href="sip..." to be a valid hyperlink.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598925/is-there-an-href-attribute-for-skype-like-mailto-or-tel?

Comment: Thanks for the reference this solutions doesn't work for Skype for Business.