# Href with skype links is not displayed

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
if (!empty($row['skype'])) {
  echo "<b>Skype:</b> " . $row['skype'] . " <a href=\"skype:venci?chat\">Chat</a>";
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not display as hyperlink on my website. If I change it to:

```
if (!empty($row['skype'])) {
  echo "<b>Skype:</b> " . $row['skype'] . " <a href=/\"skype:venci?chat\">Chat</a>";
}
```

The link is displayed, but it is broken - it leads to www.domain.com/%22skype:venci?chat%22

I have other hrefs in my page like:

```
echo "<b>E-Mail:</b> <a href=mailto:" . $row['email'] .">" . $row['email'] . "</a><br />";
```

and these are displayed correctly, so I'm wondering.. Why is this not working?

Comment: Read this, perhaps it has the answer you seek - specifically about what you need to do to your Skype account to make this work. [Is there an href attribute for skype, like “mailto:” or “tel:”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598925/is-there-an-href-attribute-for-skype-like-mailto-or-tel)

Comment: @EGC if I write the code in a different webpage (empty, containing only
<?PHP
     echo "<a href=\"skype:venci?chat\">Chat</a>"
?>, it works like a charm..

Comment: @PunkoHead What is displayed instead? and what is the final HTML that your PHP is outputting in the page source? may be there is some client side code that manipulates the links.

Comment: @Accountantم the final html is <a href="skype:venci?chat">Chat</a> so I do not see a reason for this not to work. I will check if bootstrap has something to do with manipulating the links, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It lies within the popover component in bootstrap. Thanks to all guys!

It looks like the popover does not support all href types :)